# Android ListView/Recyclerview dynamic content

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-recyclerview

Hello I am iOS developer just started with android, I know basic concepts of android like RecyclerView, ListView.

I want to make a feed page in which each row can contain one photo and multiple comments, no of comments are dynamically changing depending on data.

How to achieve the same using RecyclerView/ListView?

I can achieve the same in iOS like this : http://t.co/z1IRHTTjED

Answer (score 0):

If you already know concepts of ListView and RecyclerView you should know that we use Adapters to provide views for List.

You can create a custom Adapter which will create a view, where, depends on data you have, you will display comments or not.

**Edit.**
For example you have a layout like this

```
<LinearLayout>

<ImageView />

<TextView android:id="@+id/comments" />

</LinearLayout>
```

in your adapter you should call

```
TextView comments = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.comments);
if(haveComments) {
    comments.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    //display comments
} else {
    comments.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

If you need to have more complex layout for comments, for example with images, and date field, instead of TextView declare LinearLayout with vertical orientation. You can fill it with items from code.

```
 LinearLayout commentsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.commentsLayout);
    if(haveComments) {
        comments.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //display comments
        commentsLayout.addView(inflateCommentView());
    } else {
        comments.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

private View inflateCommentView() {
     View myComment =  LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.my_complex_comment, null);
     //set listeners, fill with data
     return myComment;
}
```

Comment: How to put dynamic no of textviews in View?

Comment: adapter have a method `getCount()` just change that value.